How to get the most suitable font according to the LANGID returned by GetSystemDefaultLangID?
EnumFontFamiliesExW returns too many duplicated font face names that is not suitable to render all of them to let users choose. I am using lpelfe->lfCharSet of EnumFontFamExProc to filter and hope to get the best one.
int CALLBACK EnumFontFamExProc(
   const LOGFONT    *lpelfe,
   const TEXTMETRIC *lpntme,
         DWORD      FontType,
         LPARAM     lParam
);

The filter algorithm is based on the return of GetSystemDefaultLangID and this is my code.
    switch (GetSystemDefaultLangID()) {
    case 0x0004/*zh-Hans*/:
    case 0x0804/*zh-CN*/:
    case 0x1004/*zh-SG*/:
    case 0x7804/*zh*/:
        preferCharSet = GB2312_CHARSET;
        break;
    case 0x7C04/*zh-Hant*/:
    case 0x0404/*zh-TW*/:
    case 0x0C04/*zh-HK*/:
    case 0x1404/*zh-MO*/:
        preferCharSet = CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET;
        break;
    case 0x0011/*ja*/:
    case 0x0411/*ja-JP*/:
    case 0x0811/*ja-Ploc-JP, reserved*/:
        preferCharSet = SHIFTJIS_CHARSET;
        break;
    /*omit others*/
    }


GB2312_CHARSET, CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET and SHIFTJIS_CHARSET are defined in WinGDI.h as follows:
#define ANSI_CHARSET            0
#define DEFAULT_CHARSET         1
#define SYMBOL_CHARSET          2
#define SHIFTJIS_CHARSET        128
#define HANGEUL_CHARSET         129
#define HANGUL_CHARSET          129
#define GB2312_CHARSET          134
#define CHINESEBIG5_CHARSET     136
#define OEM_CHARSET             255
#if(WINVER >= 0x0400)
#define JOHAB_CHARSET           130
#define HEBREW_CHARSET          177
#define ARABIC_CHARSET          178
#define GREEK_CHARSET           161
#define TURKISH_CHARSET         162
#define VIETNAMESE_CHARSET      163
#define THAI_CHARSET            222
#define EASTEUROPE_CHARSET      238
#define RUSSIAN_CHARSET         204

#define MAC_CHARSET             77
#define BALTIC_CHARSET          186


My switch case statement does not include all languages, 0x0439 India language for example, I cannot find a constant above for Hindi font. I am wondering if there is way to find the Windows system preference XXX_CHARSET according to LANGID.

Would't EnumFontFamiliesW correct your problem? It doesn't enumerate all the charset.

I wrote EnumFontFamiliesW, not EnumFontFamiliesExW

The output of EnumFontFamiliesW is very similar to mine, but not exactly the same. Perhaps the charset-mapping algorithms are different. EnumFontFamiliesW can output more fonts BTW.

Charsets are a legacy thing that correspond to code pages for 8-bit and multi-byte pre-Unicode encodings. Fonts have a data table called the 'OS/2' table (yes, it dates to the OS/2 operating system) that includes a bit-field used to declare code pages that can be supported. EnumFontFamiliesEx will call the callback function once for each Windows code page that was indicated in the OS/2 table. It does this whether or not an lfFacename string was passed in; in other words, it treats the charset variants as through they were separate font families.
Unless you are maintaining really old code that still uses code pages, none of the charset variants matter: you can filter to any charset.
If the LOGFONT you pass into EnumFontFamiliesEx has a charset indicated, then GDI will filter fonts based on that. Most fonts have the "ANSI" charset (i.e., code page 1252) indicated, but definitely not all. E.g., Windows ships with some Japanese fonts that only have ShiftJIS charset set. So, unfortunately it wouldn't be reliable to let GDI filter by setting the charset up front unless you know you only need fonts for that specific charset — but it sounds like that's not your scenario (e.g., you mention Hindi).
Also, some raster fonts, such as Terminal, have bitmap-size variants, and in some cases GDI will enumerate each of those variants in separate callbacks. (The LOGFONTs returned in the callback will have different lfHeight or lfWidth values.) Those differences probably also aren't relevant for you.
So, what I suggest is that you filter in the callbacks. For instance, set up a set and in each callback search for the returned lfFacename in the set. If found, continue (ignore); else add the lfFacename to the set.

The above addresses your remark about "too many duplicated font face names", but your actual question appears to be,

I am wondering if there is way to find the Windows system preference XXX_CHARSET according to LANGID.

You mention GetSystemDefaultLangID(). That function is really only relevant for legacy, non-Unicode applications:

Returns the language identifier for the system locale. This is the language used when displaying text in programs that do not support Unicode.

If that really fits your purpose, then you can call GetLocaleInfoA() passing MAKELCID(langid, SORT_DEFAULT) for the Locale parameter; or instead of calling GetSystemDefaultLangID(), call GetSystemDefaultLCID. And, in the call to GetLocaleInfoA(), pass LOCALE_FONTSIGNATURE for the LCType; a LOCALESIGNATURE will be returned. The lsCsbDefault member of that structure will specify the default OEM and ANSI code pages. You can then call TranslateCharsetInfo() to map a code page to a GDI charset.

OK, but note that specifying a charset can filter out a lot of fonts that might otherwise be enumerated. For example, on my current system, if EnumFontFamiliesEx is called passing a logfont with lfCharset == DEFAULT_CHARSET, then the callback will get called 2,402 times (with 587 unique lfFacename values across all those calls). But if the logfont passed in has lfCharset == SHIFTJIS_CHARSET, then the callback will get called only 126 times with 126 different lfFacename values. [cont'd,,,]

So, what to do depends on your requirements. If you want fonts that support a particular legacy code page, then setting lfCharset to something other than DEFAULT_CHARSET might be helpful, but it certainly won't get you all the fonts on the system. Your question started out by remaining on "too many duplicated font face names", so I explained that and what I suggested for filtering addresses that whether you pass in a specific charset or not. But I see now that that wasn't what you asked at the end of the question, so I'll turn to that.

You haven't really explained what it is you're trying to accomplish. Why would you care about GetACP(), which is really only relevant for legacy, non-Unicode applications?

I am creating a font list and let users choose. The fonts system prefers will be at the top of the list. Although GetACP() does not return LANGID like GetSystemdefaultLangID() does, it returns the most similar result. My app is of Unicode, but it is not related to this problem. EnumFontFamiliesExW is called first with DEFAULT_CHARSET set, filtering occurs in the callback EnumFontFamExProc and filter condition is that the lpelfe->lfCharSet is set to the system preference charset which I want to get ultimately.

Only one font face name will be remained for a font family that matchs the preference charset. An English Windows can be set to another language for non-Unicode application. Why should the user set it, perhaps the language is the main language he/she is using. GetSystemDefaultLangID() can report the language. If the language for non-Unicode has never been set to others, GetSystemDefaultLangID() returns the system default LANGID which also is accepted. As an international application, no arguments can be provided to MAKELCID. If exist, they must be the outputs of a system API calling.

"The fonts system prefers will be at the top of the list." Don't assume that the system locale setting represents what will be most relevant for users: It's not uncommon for non-English users to have a system with system locale set to en-US. If the font list is to allow users to format content they are creating, then what is more relevant is the languages in which they can edit content, i.e., languages for which they have keyboards configured. The relevant concept is the user profile languages: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/manage-language-and-region

You might also want to consider the LanguageFontGroup API: it provides recommended fonts for a language for different usage scenarios.

Btw, I'm curious why you are using GDI and not DirectWrite?

if DirectWrite can implement the aim, that is great. the primary probelm is if there is a mechanic to map a LANGID to a lpelfe->lfCharSet of EnumFontFamExProc(const LOGFONTW *lpelfe, const TEXTMETRICW *lpntme, DWORD FontType, LPARAM lParam). so far I'm using my mapping method, it's okay, just curious why Microfoft does not provide one. BTW, there are lots of problem about EnumFontFamiliesExW. Thank you for your feedback.

Charsets are obsolete. They weren't designed to support your scenario, and that won't change. For what you want to do, IDWriteFontSet1::GetFilteredFonts using DWRITE_FONT_PROPERTY_ID_DESIGN_SCRIPT_LANGUAGE_TAG seems more useful.

Charsets are really obsoleted? if the system only returns Unicode, is it kind of boring?

Charsets were designed for legacy, pre-Unicode text support in the early 1990s. You can still use them, but they're limited in capabilities to what was needed circa 1992, and aren't useful for global requirements of today.
